# React error: Style prop value must be an object react/style-prop-object

Tags: html, reactjs, image

I am trying to wrap text around an image and if I use the following code:

```
<div className="container">
         <img src={myImageSource} alt="swimmer" height="300" width="300" style="float: left" />
         <p> This is where the other text goes about the swimmer</p>
 </div>
```

Now I understand that this `style="float: left"` is html 5.  However if I use the following code:

```
<div className="container">
         <img src={myImageSource} alt="swimmer" height="300" width="300" align="left" />
            <p> This is where the other text goes about the swimmer</p>
 </div>
```

It works! Why can't I use style in React?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can still use style in react. Try : 
`style={{float: 'left'}}`

Answer (score 22):

The issue is you are passing style as a `String` instead of an `Object`. React expects you to pass style in an object notation:

```
style={{ float:`left` }}  // Object literal notation
```

or another way would be:

```
const divStyle = {
  margin: '40px',
  border: '5px solid pink'
};

<div style={divStyle}>   // Passing style as an object
```

See the [documentation for more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Answer (score 14):

In case if a property(e.g. 'align-self') has special characters, you need use single quotes for property name as well, e.g

```
style={{'align-self':'flex-end'}}
```

You may see a warning "Unsupported style property align-self. Did you mean alignSelf?",  but the style is copied correctly to generated html `align-self: flex-end;`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style):

> The **style** attribute accepts a JavaScript object with **camelCased properties(`style={{float: 'left'}}`)** rather than a **CSS string (`style="float: left"`)**. *This is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient*, and prevents XSS security holes.

So you should write it as:

```
<img src={myImageSource} alt="swimmer" height="300" width="300" style={{float: 'left'}} />
```

Comment: Thanks to all those who contributed.  Treat style as an object.

Answer (score 2):

As other has stated. When copying from HTML, it gets string `style="string: string"`.
You need to go `style={{property: "value"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding ' before and after the style class and the value worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write inline style in react as `style={{float: 'left'}}`

And if you want to use more than one property you can use it as object as below to avoid lint errors.

```
const imgStyle = {
  margin: '10px',
  border: '1px solid #ccc',
  float: 'left',
  height: '300px',
  width: '300px'
};

<div className="container">
         <img src={imgStyle} alt="swimmer" />
         <p> This is where the other text goes about the swimmer</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple inline styles, this is how I did it.

Separate each style into its own object:

```
const style1={'text-align':'center'};
const style2={'color':'red'};
```

Then use those objects like this: (include 3 dots, separated by comma)

```
<h1 style={{...style1,...style2}}>Two Styles</h1>
```

My example below:

```
export default function myFunction() {
    const style1={'text-align':'center'};
    const style2={'color':'red'};

    return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{...style1,...style2}}>Two Styles</h1>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div className="container">
   <img src={myImageSource} alt="swimmer" height="300" width="300" **style={{align:'left'}}** />
   <p> This is where the other text goes about the swimmer</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.